# Macro - Variables - Email layout

Tags: excel, email, vba

I have built a macro to send emails automatically each month, but I want the body of the to look more professional, I have tried everything. I have to use the code below for the email part , but I need to put a new line where the "&" in the body varible.

Could some help many thanks !

below are 4 varibles going into one vairlbe but need to split the below varibles

Body = Intro **&** Part1 **&** Part2  **&** Footer

Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

```
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

On Error Resume Next
 With OutMail

    .To = emailTo
    .CC = emailCc
    .BCC = emailBcc
    .subject = subject
    .HTMLBody = Body
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the HTML fragments of the parts you are concatenating, it might helpt to place proper line breaks inbetween:

```
Body = Intro & "<br/>" & Part1 & "<br/>" & Part2 & "<br/>" & Footer
```

Knowing more details of your parts, there might be a better solution.